# Choosing a back-up smartphone

Tags: smartphones, mobile-phone

Because I will have to send my OnePlus 2 away for repairs, I have been looking for a solid back-up phone that compensates for the features my current phone lacks (expandable storage and quick charging).

I have looked into phones from Xiaomi and LeEco since they have interesting phones such as the Mi Max and the LeMax 2. Both phones have distinctive features for a price that cannot be ignored.

Watching a lot of reviews, here are the things I like/dislike about both phones:

**Xiaomi Mi Max**

- Has a huge screen coming in at 6.44 inch
- Has a large battery that lasts two to three days for more users
- The version I want to get, sports 4 gigs of RAM and 128 gigs of storage
- Has the option to expand the storage with an additional SD card
- The 16 MP camera is decent during the day but mediocre in low light situations
- The build quality is not on par with the LeMax 2
- Still uses micro USB for data transfer and charging

**LeEco LeMax 2**

- Incredible specs at a very decent price (4 gigs of RAM, a Snapdragon 820 SoC and a 21 MP camera)
- Uses USB-C for data transfer and charging
- Has a better camera than the Mi Max on the front and the back
- Lacks a dedicated audio jack (but an adapter is included)
- Storage is not (easily) expandable
- The battery is of a lesser capacity than the Mi Max

**Where and what will I be using it for?**

I'll be mainly using it to series and movies when I'm traveling. I will also use the phone at festivals and conventions to ocassionally take pictures and record videos.

That left me in the middle since the Mi Max sounds like the perfect phone to consume media without having to worry about the battery running dry.

On the other hand, the LeEco has the superior specs and might even beat my OnePlus Two but the storage is not expandable which is a pity....

Which phone would suit my needs based on what both phones offer?

Note: I already have a few shops where I can order the phones so that won't necessary.

Comment: Is carrying a USB battery pack a viable option for you?  How about an external hdd with either USB, bluetooth, wifi connectvity to sync your photos.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an expandable, very reliable, pretty cheap backup phone I would go with an Samsung S5. Does not have the great specs you listed but it may be alot more reliable.

Comment: Hmm...It does sound like a viable option but the battery and bigger screen do weigh a bit more. I have also looked into the Lenovo P2 which has an even larger battery and has the same price as the Mi Max that I want to purchase. I'll try to look into both phones before I decide to buy one.